# get content align center

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

im trying to build a profile card view and im using bootstrap for it.

i build two div elements on with the class col-lg-3 and the other one with col-lg-9. the problem is that the content inside the col-lg-9 is not align in the center. it has more space on the right side as on the left side and i tryde almost everything to get them center. disabled margin and padding didnt worked.

the col-lg-9 is inside a row and a normal container. and inside the col-lg-9 is the content. i have here a sample on[bootplay](http://www.bootply.com/bZRbqUQENa) if ya marke the container you can see that the contents with the class card hase right more space.

thats the html code of it

```
            <div class="col-lg-9" style="min-height: 100px; background-color: #333">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="model-image">
                        <img src="img/elliot.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <a class="card-header">Team Fu</a>
                     <div class="meta">
                        <span class="date">Create in Sep 2014</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="#">ds</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

i uploadet so ya can see the whole site. for better understanding [demo](http://kallax.awesom-media.de/models.html#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add an extra container for all .card divs you will get it centered:

```
<div class="container text-center"> 
 <div class="cards-container" style="display:inline-block; box-sizing:border-box;">

   <!-- here all your .card divs -->

  </div>
</div>
```

You can add the css of the cards-container in css file.

Comment: Didnt worked. still just like in the pic or on bootply

Comment: I just tested it on bootply and worked correctly - by adding it to your code

Comment: No problem :)  glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

When using bootstrap, just add the text-center class to your div and it will center your elements and all the children.

And i would suggest to use inline css rather put your css in a external stylesheet. It will be much easier to maintain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
<div class="card-content text-center">
    <a class="card-header">Team Fu</a>
    <div class="meta">
    <span class="date">Create in Sep 2014</span>
</div>
```